# Macro which will loop through a range to populate coordinate values of adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop, range

I am helping to modify an excel spreadsheet for a camera calibration lab. The original calibration lab had only one station with 14 fixed targets, which allowed for the targets' `X, Y, & Z` coordinates to be hard coded into spreadsheet.

The new lab has 90+ targets with multiple stations possible.  I wanted to make a macros which would allow a user to simply insert target numbers to a range of cells, when the macro is run the three columns (ranges) adjacent to the first would populate with each targets corresponding coordinates.

The coordinate would preferable be stored in another sheet, ordered by target number with their `X, Y, & Z` coordinates in cells to the right.

I was thinking the code would be something like;

```
  Define range of target numbers
  for each cell in range, 
  If cell(2,4) =  1 then ' 1 is the target number
  cell(2,5) = cell(1,2) ' from another worksheet x value
  cell(2,6) = cell(1,3) ' Y value
  cell(2,7) = cell(1,4) ' Z value
  end if
```

The user would use 14 targets, having an option of any targets.

Comment: Please edit your question and format it properly. It's a very hard to read wall of text. Take a look at the formatting help to learn about markdown formatting if you need assistance.